# elasticsearch and postfix log analysis

Tags: php, elasticsearch

We have an elasticsearch monitoring postfix mail log. Every month we generate statistics based on this postfix log and we make it with remote query via PHP on logstash indexes generated for the last 30 days.

The PHP script search, for a given `sasl_username` or a given IP (based on authentication type), all the queue_id and stores it in an array divided into blocks of 1024 values (where 1024 is the max clause count configured in elasticsearch).

After that the script loops over the array of `queue_id` and builds a string per every block with the `queue_ids` in OR and then sends a query filtering on this `queue_ids` string.

The following code should clarify:

```
$url_count = "http://xxxxxxxxx:9200/logstash-*/_search?search_type=count";
$url_search = "http://xxxxxxxxx:9200/logstash-*/_search?pretty";

$query_count_sasl_username = '{"query": {
                                "filtered": {
                                    "query": {
                                        "range" : { 
                                            "@timestamp" : { 
                                                "gte" : "now-30d/d", 
                                                "lt" : "now/d" 
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "filter":{
                                        "bool":{
                                            "must":[{
                                                "query":{
                                                    "match":{
                                                        "sasl_username":{
                                                            "query": "' . $username . '","type":"phrase"
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }]
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }}';

    $res = exec_curl($url_count, $query_count_sasl_username);

    $n_totale_records = json_decode($res)->hits->total;

    $query_get_all_sasl_username = ' {"fields" : ["queue_id"],"query": {"filtered": {"query": {"range" : { "@timestamp" : { "gte" : "now-30d/d", "lt" : "now/d" }}},
    "filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"query":{"match":{"sasl_username":{"query":"' . $username . '","type":"phrase"}}}}]}}}}, 
    "size": ' .  $n_totale_records . '}';

    $all_sasl_username = exec_curl($url_search, $query_get_all_sasl_username);
    //returns all with sasl_username searched
    $array_result = json_decode($all_sasl_username);
    $array_domains = array();
    $array_from = array();

    $ids = array();
    $ids_str_tmp = "";
    $tmp_index_count = 0;

    for($i = 0; $i < count($array_result->hits->hits); $i++){       
        $ids_str_tmp .=  "\\\"" . $array_result->hits->hits[$i]->fields->queue_id[0] ."\\\"";

        if($tmp_index_count != $MAX_CLAUSE_COUNT - 1 && $i != count($array_result->hits->hits) - 1){
            $ids_str_tmp .= " OR ";
        }

        if($tmp_index_count == $MAX_CLAUSE_COUNT - 1 || $i == count($array_result->hits->hits) - 1){
            array_push($ids, $ids_str_tmp);
            $ids_str_tmp = "";
            $tmp_index_count = 0;
        }
        else{
            $tmp_index_count++;
        }
    }

    //now I have all json node with queue_id searched divided into blocks of 1024
    for($i = 0; $i < count($ids); $i++){
        $query_get_by_ids_count = '{"query":{
                                        "filtered": {
                                            "query": {
                                              "range" : { 
                                                "@timestamp" : { 
                                                  "gte" : "now-30d/d", "lt" : "now/d"
                                                }
                                              }
                                            },"filter":{
                                                "query_string":{
                                                    "query":"queue_id: ' . $ids[$i] . '"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }}';

        $res = exec_curl($url_count, $query_get_by_ids_count);

        $size_elements = json_decode($res)->hits->total;

        $query_get_by_ids = '{"query":{
                                "filtered": {
                                    "query": {
                                        "range" : {
                                            "@timestamp" : { 
                                                "gte" : "now-30d/d", "lt" : "now/d"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "filter":{
                                        "query_string":{
                                            "query":"queue_id: ' . $ids[$i] . '"}
                                        }
                                    }
                                }, 
                                "size": ' .  $size_elements . 
                            '}';

        $all_by_queue_id = exec_curl($url_search, $query_get_by_ids);

        $array_all_by_queue_id = json_decode($all_by_queue_id);
        //check in every node for field from and save it in an array
        for($j = 0; $j < count($array_all_by_queue_id->hits->hits); $j++){
            if(property_exists($array_all_by_queue_id->hits->hits[$j]->_source, "from")){
                array_push($array_from,$array_all_by_queue_id->hits->hits[$j]->_source->from);
                array_push($array_domains,  substr($array_all_by_queue_id->hits->hits[$j]->_source->from, strrpos($array_all_by_queue_id->hits->hits[$j]->_source->from, "@") + 1));
            }
        }
    }
```

The problems is on the performance of this script, it takes about 5 seconds for a user with 1670 different `queue_id` on `postfix_log` in one day.
I think that problem is on creation on OR blocks that slow down the performance, because when the query is launched, the response is fast.

Is there any way to improve performance or a different method to do statistics on postfix log with elasticsearch?